# "cannot convert argument 1 from 'Node<T>' to 'std::nullptr_t" compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I am writing program with templates in C++, but I can't figure out why it's not compiling.

I have class Node:

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
friend class Tree<T>;

public:
using nodePtr = std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>;
Node(T value):
    nodeValue(value),
    leftSon(Node()),
    rightSon(Node()),
    isEmpty(false) {
}

Node(T value, nodePtr left, nodePtr right):
    nodeValue(value),
    leftSon(left),
    rightSon(right),
    isEmpty(false) {
}

Node():
    nodeValue(T()),
    leftSon(nullptr),
    rightSon(nullptr),
    isEmpty(true) {
}

Node(nodePtr root):
    nodeValue(root->nodeValue),
    leftSon(root->leftSon),
    rightSon(root->rightSon),
    isEmpty(root->isEmpty) {
}

Node(const nodePtr& copied):
    nodeValue(copied.nodeValue),
    leftSon(copied.leftSon),
    rightSon(copied.rightSon),
    isEmpty(copied.isEmpty) {
}

private:
T nodeValue;
nodePtr leftSon;
nodePtr rightSon;
bool isEmpty;
};
```

and Tree:

```
template<typename T>
class Tree {
using nodePtr = std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>;

nodePtr root;

public:
static nodePtr createEmptyNode() {
    return std::make_shared<Node<T>>();
}

static nodePtr createValueNode(T value) {
    return std::make_shared<Node<T>>(value);
}

static nodePtr createValueNode(T value, nodePtr left, nodePtr right) {
    return std::make_shared<Node<T>>(value, left, right);
}
};
```

When I'm using

```
Tree<int>::createValueNode(7);
```

in main function, Visual Studio compiler ends with error:

```
C2664   
'std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>::shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> &&) noexcept':
 cannot convert argument 1 from 'Node<T>' to 'std::nullptr_t'
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Try to write < Node<T> > - add space symbol between >>

Comment: I don't know what debugger is it. In options i see "Debugger to launch: Local Windows Debugger".

Comment: With '> >' there is the same error

Comment: I think the problem is in the first constructor of the Node class. Try to assign nullptr to left and right son and see if it compile.

Comment: You should take my response as the accepted one cause I first pointed out the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment the problem is the first constructor in Node class. You could change it with a null value like this:

```
Node(T value):
    nodeValue(value),
    leftSon(nullptr),
    rightSon(nullptr),
    isEmpty(false) {
}
```

You could also initialize with a new Node class like this:

```
Node(T value):
    nodeValue(value),
    leftSon(new Node()),
    rightSon(new Node()),
    isEmpty(false) {
}
```

The solution you will use depends on the meaning of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Error message is indeed unclear. clang one is better:

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of '`nodePtr`' (aka `shared_ptr<Node<int> >`')

```
leftSon(Node()),  
^       ~~~~~~
```

Error is here

```
Node(T value):
    nodeValue(value),
    leftSon(Node()), // <-
    rightSon(Node()), // <-
    isEmpty(false) {
}
```

It should be:

```
Node(T value):
    nodeValue(value),
    leftSon(),
    rightSon(),
    isEmpty(false) {
}
```

depending of what you want.

Comment: Copied from my comment 5 minutes late.

Comment: @KakamiOkatsu: Honestly, I see your comment after found the solution by compiling with clang/gcc.